# Installing Ia32build (Intel assembler) in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, x86

I am looking for a assembler, in my college there is a ia32build assembler. I have tried searching it in Google, but I can't find it. I have x86 processor and I want to install it in Ubuntu 10.4.

**Edit 1 :** I am not sure about the assembler name but we assemble it by ia32build command.

**Edit 2 :** The syntax is quite different from nasm. Here's my sample code.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.text
    msg:    .asciz  "Hello World !"

_entry:

    Prompt msg

.global _entry

.end
```

Thanks.

Comment: You've got me curious, what is an intel assembler?  Sorry that I can't help.

Comment: @KronoS Sorry, I meant to say assembler for Intel processor.

Comment: @Searock You should probably try asking at your college. It could very easily happen that you use a custom made program there and there.

Comment: What do you mean my custom made program? can you please elaborate? Do you mean to say that the custom program is x86 assemblers?

Comment: @Searock  OK, I'll have to make a bit longer explanation. Google search didn't give any meaningful results for ia32build, so it's not well known assembler. It could happen that someone from  your collage programmed or hired somebody to program the ia32build specifically for use at your collage. If that is true, then only way to obtain the program would be from someone related to your college. You could try asking other students or professors who teach the subject where you use the ia32build.

Comment: My professor told us that instruction set for different processor is different, so will instruction set vary from assembler to assembler?

Comment: @Searock Aha! You seem to be confusing assembler and assembly! Those are two different things. Assembly is the instruction set and each processor has its own instruction set. Assembler turns assembly into machine language (ones and zeroes) used by the processor. Assembly may be different for different assemblers, even if the instruction set is same. Take a look at styles section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language Since you seem to be confused by this, it'd be best for you to use assembler provided by your collage.

Comment: Now that I think of this, you may want to post  samples of your code at http://stackoverflow.com/ and ask people there to identify the syntax.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Thanks, for clearing the confusion. I think Jan Claeys has helped me in identifying the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default assembler on linux and many other open source systems is `as` (aka GAS, and part of `binutils` in the GCC compiler toolchain).  It supports IA32 as well as lots of other architectures.

Alternatively, you can use `nasm` or `yasm`.

One thing about GAS (the GNU assembler) is that it uses a different syntax from what most people are used to (that is, the syntax used by most other assemblers).  There is a tool to convert from "intel" to "gas" syntax though, appropriately named `intel2gas`.

**Edit:** actually, your syntax looks like GAS syntax...

Comment: (+1) and how do I assemble using GAS command?

Comment: I have never used it directly, but I assume `as filename` should work, maybe with some additional options.  And `info as` should show you the whole documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the `ia32build` assembler, however both [Nasm](http://www.nasm.us/) and [Yasm](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/) are both commonly used x86 assemblers.  I personally have only ever used Nasm.  It seems to be a bit more mature with more documentation, but either one should work for you on Ubuntu.